# The data source provider for data sources of type 'ADOMD.NET' is not registered

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint, adomd.net

I am working on sharepoint 2013 ,while working on Performance Point Service when i amd connecting to a new Analysis source in Dashboard Designer ,it is not loading databases.

I have googled the problem and found the in my EventLogs it appears 
"The data source provider for data sources of type 'ADOMD.NET' is not registered. Please contact an administrator.PerformancePoint Services error code 10115."

I downloaded and installed latest version of ADOMD.NET but it didnt worked.Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer, and SharePoint Server 2013, it will try to load the SQL Server 2008 version of the ADMD.NET dll.

Try to install the SQL Server 2008 R2 ADMD.NET component from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978 and restart IIS.